# How to create density independent full screen image for Android ported from iOS

Tags: android, image, android-layout, android-studio

I have a full screen image representing the home screen of an iOS app that I would like to reuse in an Android app. I've read the Android documentation on density independent pixels. I've read that the system performs scaling and resizing to make your application work on different screens, but that there is the need to create images for each of the density buckets to maximize the experience.

As I understand it, the following "common" screen sizes often have associated density buckets that the screen sizes fall into (but not always):

480x800 pixels -> hdpi (240 dpi)
720x1280 pixels -> xhdpi (320 dpi)
1080x1920 pixels -> xxhdpi (480 dpi)

So, to test my understanding, I tweaked my full screen image to fit these screen sizes and densities. For each, I create a new image in photoshop to fit the specific screen size. Then I resized the image and changed the document size to a width of 384 points (constrained). I also tried widths of 320 and 360. I saved this out as a png file and loaded each image for each screen size into drawable directories "drawable-hdpi", "drawable-xhdpi", and drawable-xxhdpi". These values were chosen based on the document [Metrics and Grids | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html).

Next I used "Android Studio" to create a layout. I also added a button to lay on top of a portion of the image where my app needs a button.

The problem is that both the emulator and the Android Studio layout editor are showing white shadow boxes on the sides of the image for each of the device configurations. Android is NOT scaling or resizing. In reality, I don't really want it to resize it if its going to stretch it awkwardly, but I do not understand why the layout editor and the emulator are putting white bars on the side of the image.

In addition, the button does not stay in the same position on the image.

Please help me understand what is wrong with the following layout. How can I create a layout for a full screen image that fills the screen for most devices and how can I define a button that is fixed to the same spot on the image (e.g. relative to the lower left corner of the image)?

Here is the XML from the layout that is created by Android Studio:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    tools:context="com.myCompany.myApp.MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:src="@drawable/android_home_screen1" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Channel 1"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_marginBottom="128dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I've noticed that if I make the image be exactly 480x690 pixels, then the full screen image fits perfectly into any of the hdpi devices within Android Studio. However, it still has white side bars for the emulator AVD set up with an hdpi device. Shouldn't the emulator be the same as the layout editor?

Comment: Similarly, if I make the xhdpi image be exactly 720x1040 (not 1280), then the full screen image fits perfectly into an xhdpi device such as Galaxy Nexus that is 720x1280, but it does not get stretched to fit into a device such as the Nexus 4 which is an xhdpi device with a screen size of 768x1280. So why doesn't Android stretch this to fit as advertised?